# Using Dojo 1.9, all parsing fails in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, parsing, dojo

So I have a rather large web app that was running Dojo 1.8.  Everything works fine in multiple versions of IE and Firefox.  I decided to give 1.9 a go and changed my dependency from 1.8 to 1.9.  Firefox worked fine with no noticable changes on first run.  IE versions 8 and 9, however, both failed to do much of anything at all.  All static HTML content (and dynamic jsp content) was fine, and all of the ajax calls to get the required modules seemed to work fine, but the parser acted like it wasn't ever being called.  There were no errors, warnings, or anything in the console.

I kept playing with my dojo config, which is nothing special:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: "js/",
    async: true,
    has: {
            "dojo-firebug": true,
            "dojo-debug-messages": true
    },
    parseOnLoad: false,
    isDebug: true,
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
    packages: [
        { name: "dojo", location: "dojo-release-1.9.0/dojo" },
        { name: "dijit", location: "dojo-release-1.9.0/dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location: "dojo-release-1.9.0/dojox" }
    ]
};
```

I found that if I comment out async: true, IE suddenly starts working again.  As you can imagine, I really want to have async true.  Why is this tripping IE up?  I hope I've provided enough info.

edit:  I invoke the parser by including a script tag at the bottom of the  tag for a file called common.js, which looks roughly like this:

```
require([
    "dojo/parser", 
    "dojo/ready"
    ], 
    function(parser, ready){
        ready(function(){
            parser.parse();    
        });
    });
```

I've tried swapping out dojo/ready for dojo/domReady! and taking the parser.parse out of the ready(function(){ block too with the same results.

Comment: Wished I had a solution for you.  All I can say is that IE is the biggest piece of crap out there.  It gives me nothing but problems.  Special workarounds I create are always IE related.  Anyhow, the bright point here is that I've always been able to find a workaround for IE garbage...

Comment: how/where are you invoking the parser?

Comment: I've got the same issue with Dojo 1.9 and IE10

Comment: thanks for the comments.  i just updated my question with info about how i'm invoking the parser.

Comment: How did you verify that the problem lies within the parser.parse call?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the entire dom loads.  If you view source on the page, all of the HTML is there just as it looks in the source, but none of the declarative widgets actually get instantiated. So it seems that it's not getting parsed.

Comment: I am seeing this also.  It appears that the problem is the ready function never executes.  Try adding an alert before your `parse()` call - I think you'll see it never executes.

Comment: Probably you are never even entering that function, so ready() isn't even getting called.   Those are the reports we've gotten from other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dare mark my own answer as correct over Bill Keese, the Dijit lead... :)

But seriously, Since Bill posted this, the actual problem has been corrected and committed.  This was addressed in ticket #17141 over at Dojo and included in the latest 1.9.1 release:

https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/query?group=status&milestone=1.9.1

Updating to this release fixes the issue and IE works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround was to copy the dijit/templates, dijit/form/templates, and dijit/layout/templates folders from the src distribution into your dojo distribution.

See https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17141 and https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17146 for details.