# dojo doesnt work in a worklight application on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

i create a worklight 6.0.0 application (dojo 1.9) does run on chrome and firefox, but doesnt run on any version of internet explorer (tested in 6,7,9 with IE tester, and 8 native).

That is the error thats return IE.

```
Mensaje: 
Línea: 18
Carácter: 486
Código: 0
URI: http://domain/context/apps/services/www/appname/desktopbrowser/default/dojo/dojo.js


Mensaje: Se esperaba un identificador, una cadena o un número
Línea: 409
Carácter: 3
Código: 0
URI: http://domain/context/apps/services/www/appname/desktopbrowser/default/js/CoopServidoresApp.js
```

and this is my dojo config in my Main Worklight Html.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false"
src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

I create another application from the start and then run it from internet explorer and doesnt work eather.
Is there any configuration does i need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: [Using Dojo 1.9, all parsing fails in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544436/using-dojo-1-9-all-parsing-fails-in-ie)

It looks like dojo 1.9.0 is busted in IE.   The fix seems to be to in 1.9.1

Comment: how can i change the version of the dojo on my default dojoLib?